# Why does FindFirst in UIAutomation takes so long?

Tags: c#, mfc, ui-automation

I'm trying to automate a part of our application WinForms/MFC application (to be able to perform automated tests) - however, currently I'm struggling with slow finding of the main menu (SysTreeView32 control) - basically the central component, which enables access to all the screens which I need to test.

I tried to find it with `AutomationElement.FindFirst()`, also with the `TreeWalker.GetFirstChild()`, but both methods seem far too slow.

What was interesting, once I started interaction with this TreeView during the time the test was trying to find the control - like expand/collapse some items, move with the mouse over the tested application - the control was found almost immediately.

What's the catch? Application is reacting very smoothly - only lookup process takes ages, when the app is inactive.

Comment: Are you trying TreeScope.Descendants in the search params? And from which AutomationElement did you start? Desktop / root?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov TreeScope.Descendants makes no difference in the search, I'm starting my search from app's main window (no desktop/root node). 

What is really confusing me is, why does UI Automation, when there is some interaction in the window, find the elements very quickly. I observed this in my code, but also with e.q. UISpy - when expanding some elements of this application's tree, expand could take longer time, but when moved cursor over the app, it was done very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to find a child of my main window. You should give as many details as you can (filter things out) so that the search goes faster. In my case, I had a Save As Window, I added the following:

- The window should be a `ControlType.Window`
- AndCondition
- The `AutomationElement.NameProperty` of the window should be: "Save As"

  var saveWindow = appElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children | TreeScope.Descendants, new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Save As")));

You need to do further tests to determine if the AutomationElement you are searching for can be found within the Descendants or the Children and skip search in one of them if necessary. In my case, the code above worked fine, but in a subsequent step, I required to find the Edit control / Text box next to "File name:" so I first created a condition:

```
var saveWindow = appElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children | TreeScope.Descendants, new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Save As")));
```

And then added the condition to the search:

```
var fileName = saveWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children | TreeScope.Descendants, fileNameCondition);
```

Strangely, and probably because of UIAutomation limitations, and unexpected behaviour, the line above was finding the element instantly in a Windows 10 Creators Update machine, but was getting stuck in a Windows 10 Anniversary Update... so after some debugging I found out that I could find the element by just searching in the children and that found it instantly in. both machines:

```
var fileName = saveWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, fileNameCondition);
```

Comment: Note that 'Children' and 'Descendents' are not the same.  'Children' means immediate children of the parent, where 'Descendents' also includes children of the children (and their children).  'Descendents' can be a very deep search hierarchy and can lead to performance concerns.  If you know your element is a direct child, always use 'Children'.  Searching 'Descedents' and 'Children' is redundant since 'Descendents' also includes 'Children'.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.treescope